# How to execute a bit operation in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, bitwise-operators

I am trying to create a where clause using bitwise operators in sequelize.

Assuming I have a collection of of buildings, each has a function determined by the bitwise operator.

bitwise definition being

- 1 = school,   (Binary 0001)
- 2 = church,   (Binary 0010)
- 4 = hospital, (Binary 0100)

A school which is also a church would be '3' for the bitwise, 0011 in binary.

A teaching hospital is both a school and a hospital, bitwise would be 5, 0101 in binary.

In SQL the query would be something like

`SELECT id, bitwise FROM buildings WHERE bitwise & 1 = 0;`

should return all buildings which are schools.

In sequelize I think its something like

```
const { data } = await Bulding.findAll({
   attributes:['id','bitwise'],
   where: {
     bitwise: & 1,
   },
});
```

But I am unsure how to do the actual operation as its not in the docs that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was taken from https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5207 by the author of sequelize, but adapted to your sample.  Note that Sequelize here is the Sequelize singleton, NOT the instance that you create.

```
Building.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'bitwise'],
    where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('bitwise & 1'), '!=', 0)
})
```

As an additional example, if you want multiple bitwise comparisons, you can use the comparison functions that sequelize offers:

```
Building.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'bitwise'],
    where: Sequelize.and(
        Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('bitwise & 2'), '!=', 0),
        Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal('bitwise & 4'), '=', 0)
    )
})
```

You can find these functions under http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/sequelize/